# Laravel eloquent how do I include exclude from a query a computed appended field?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, calculated-columns

I have this code which is running ok:

```
class Basket extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

...

protected $appends = [
    ...
    'price'
];

....
public function getPriceAttribute($value){
    ... some heavy computing
    return $totalPrice;
}
```

But what I see is that the computing for the price will be executed e.g. when I call

```
Basket::all();
```

which is something I want to avoid

I want it only when I do a Basket::find(id) so per single entry.

I haven't find so far how can I avoid eloquent to skip or not the getPriceAttribute

Any Idea?

Comment: i think you just need to remove the 'price' from $appends

Comment: that wont let me get price anymore when I want it , cause I cant Basket::select('price')

Comment: how about [Appending At Run Time](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-at-run-time) ?

Comment: Maybe this link can help  you https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events

Comment: Did you try this https://blog.pusher.com/advanced-laravel-eloquent-usage/

Comment: @Basharmal happending at run time... that was the missing paragraph... thanks!    $basket = Basket::find($request->id)->append('price');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created the accessor, and add the value to the appends property on the model:

```
protected $appends = [
    ...
    'price'
];
```

it needs to be appended in the controller like below

```
$basket = Basket::find($request->id)->append('price');
```